How do I recover Windows after it suddenly got deleted when using Ubuntu?
I was using Ubuntu and it suddenly crashed, a gray screen poped and I forced a shutdown, then it redirected me to a pre-boot check and it said that the Hard Drive was not installed. I saw a video on youtube and I recovered the Hard drive and I can use Ubuntu but not Windows. Also when I wanted to switch from Ubuntu to Windows I had to enter BIOS and manually set windows so I could use it, now I can't because it disappeared from the boot options.
Video:
https://youtu.be/B-YMjjmT6Zo?si=Z2wbFsTi9YO_JYUm
By the way I only changed the secure boot, I turned it on, applied changes, turned it off again and applied changes and it worked but windows was gone. The gray screen came with these message:
Failed to write entry to /var/log/journal/largestring/system.journal (24 items, 692 bytes) despite vacuming, ignoring: Input/output error


Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please edit your question to include details on what you did to recover the hard drive, like the steps you took and method you used. A link to the video would be great as well. Also, try not to use the computer as much as possible at this point until you/we know what we're dealing with and what might need to be done to recover data if necessary. Thanks.
